Postman API Fundamentals Student Expert certification
I'm working on a Postman collection that includes various API requests and tests. The collection should pass several checks, including a specific skill check where I need to set a collection variable in the Tests tab script. However, I am encountering an error when running the tests.
The specific requirement for the test is:
6. [skillcheck] Set "favoriteActor" as a collection variable using 
   pm.collectionVariables.set(...) in the Tests tab script

And I'm getting an error

Postman Test Script Error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')"

I'm getting an error when running my Postman collection:
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Your collection failed one or more Postman tests. See the errors array for details.",
    "errors": [
        {
            "test": "6. [skillcheck] Set \"favoriteActor\" as a collection variable using pm.collectionVariables set(...) in Tests tab script",
            "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')"
        }
    ]
}

Here is the relevant part of my test script:
pm.test(`6. [skillcheck] Set "favoriteActor" as a collection variable using pm.collectionVariables.set(...) in Tests tab script`, function () {
    pm.collectionVariables.set("favoriteActor", "Tony Stark");

    const favoriteActor = pm.collectionVariables.get("favoriteActor");
    pm.expect(favoriteActor).to.equal("Tony Stark");
});

I tried submitting the "Submit your Postman collection" for Postman API Fundamentals Student Expert certification and instead of getting this:
{
    "status" : "ok", 
    "message" : Congratulations! the lesson 'Submit your Postman collection' is now marked as complete."
}

I got an error:
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Your collection failed one or more Postman tests. See the errors array for details.",
    "errors": [
        {
            "test": "6. [skillcheck] Set \"favoriteActor\" as a collection variable using pm.collectionVariables set(...) in  Tests tab script",
            "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')"
        }
    ]
}


Might be a bug in Postman? Have you contacted their support people?

You haven't shown where in your Collection that you've saved that as a Collection Variable or the script that's doing that for you.

Use pm.variables.get("favoriteActor"); to retrieve variables from any scope.  No need to identify the scope such as collectionVariables when using get()

That would be good advice if the challenge wasn't specifically looking for a collection variable.
